# more efficient method of dealing with large numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I have a question in Python which I have created an answer for it, but I am trying to achieve better efficiency for the answer.

I cant use functions, recursions, only basic stuff..

The question is:

For the number 3 power 2209 there are 1000 digits. find 12 sequential numbers that it's sum is the maximal.

For example: 5 power 36 equals 14551915228366851806640625. The 12 sequential numbers that product the maximal sum are 836685180664.

```
sumOfBig=0
Big=""
x=5**36
strp=str(x)
s=len(strp)
print(x)
print()
for i in range(s-11):
    new=strp[i:i+12]
    l=0
    for j in new:
        l=l+int(j)
    print(i)
    print(new)
    print(l)
    print()
    if l>sumOfBig:
        sumOfBig=l
        Big=new
print(Big)
print(sumOfBig)
```

Do you guys have any ideas for better code?

Answer (score 4):

well, you can have more efficient way of summing the 12 sequential numbers. you can keep track of 12 sequential numbers, pop/subtract the oldest(leftmost) one from the subset's sum, push/add the newest(rightmost) one.

also, `sum(iterable)` is a built-in function.

my new code with only basic `list` and `for-loop`:

```
x = 5 ** 36
num_list = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
sumOfBig = last_sum = sum(num_list[:12])
maximal_index = 0

for i, n in enumerate(num_list[12:]):
   last_sum = last_sum + n - num_list[i]
   if last_sum > sumOfBig:
      maximal_index = i+1
      sumOfBig = last_sum


print num_list[maximal_index:maximal_index+12] #[8, 3, 6, 6, 8, 5, 1, 8, 0, 6, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 5**36
str_x = [int(i) for i in str(x)]


curBestIndex = 0
curBestSum = sum(str_x[:12])
curSum = curBestSum

for i in range(len(str_x) - 11):
    delta = str_x[i + 11] - str_x[i]
    curSum += delta
    if curSum > curBestSum:
        curBestSum = curSum
        curBestIndex = i

big = str(x)[curBestIndex : curBestIndex + 12]
print(big)
print(curBestSum)
```

Comment: nice. you can use `str_x = '0' + str_x + '0'`, and initialize curSum to -1

Comment: If only I work with a string of length > 10. I let the answer for numbers like '456' be 4+5+6.

Comment: If you already have a best sum, shouldn't you use this range: `range(1, len(str_x) - 12)`? And isn't this right: `delta = str_x[i + 12] - str_x[i]`? Your code gives the wrong answer for the sample given: `>>> big = str(x)[curBestIndex : curBestIndex + 12]
>>> print(big)
283668518066
`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that helps factor out all the occurrences of 11/12, etc.

```
MAX_LENGTH = 12
x = 5 ** 36

sequence = []
d = []

for i in str(x):
    d.append(int(i))
    if len(d) > MAX_LENGTH:
        d.pop(0)
    if sum(d) >= sum(sequence):
        sequence = list(d)

print sequence, sum(sequence)
```

RETURNS:

```
>>> 
[8, 3, 6, 6, 8, 5, 1, 8, 0, 6, 6, 4] 61
```

In accordance with the Zen of Python, "Readability Counts", and I think that single line actions presented here are much more straightforward than slicing operations, especially when considering off-by-one mistakes that come from multiple instances of hardcoding the sequence length.