# Python sum of N consecutive digits of a large number

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, sum, largenumber

I need to get the largest sum of `n` consecutive digits in a range of a large number.

For example, the range could be `5^150000`, within this range I want to find out the largest sum of 50,000 consecutive digits.

The approach I have taken of using two loops seems to never terminate. I will appreciate any input.

The code:

```
count = 0
tempsum = 0
summ = 0                 # variables init
oldlist = ''
newlist = ''
num = str(3**2209) # for example

for digit in num: # go over all the digits in the number
    while count < 12 and len(num) >= 12 : # check in 12-digits blocks while possible
        oldlist += num[count] # update old list with new digit
        tempsum += int(num[count]) # add current digit to sum
        count += 1

    if tempsum > summ: # check if new sum is larger than old one
        summ = tempsum # update sum
        newlist = oldlist # update the sequence list
    oldlist = ''
    count = 0
    tempsum = 0
    num = num[1:] # slice the 'first' digit of the number

print(newlist, summ) # print sequence and desired sum
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300995/more-efficient-method-of-dealing-with-large-numbers-in-python At least, it is based on the same math problem. I don't understand why this was closed as `too localized`. The other one was closed as `not a real question`. I think the techniques in both are general enough to be useful to later SO-ers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need two loops.

First, let's put all the digits in a list:

```
>>> a = list(map(int, str(5**150000)))
```

Then calculate the sum of the first 50000 digits:

```
>>> maximum = current = sum(a[:50000])
>>> current
225318
```

Now, let's loop through the list, removing the lowest digit from the sum and adding the next one 50000 digits ahead during each iteration:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(a)-50000):
...     current = current - a[i] + a[i+50000]
```

Check if that new sum is larger than the previous one, and if so, make it the new "interim maximum":

```
...     if current > maximum: maximum = current
...
```

Once the loop exits, `maximum` contains the maximum value:

```
>>> maximum
225621
```

Let's put it all into a function, so no copying mistakes occur:

```
def maxdigitsum(number, digits):
    l = list(map(int, str(number)))
    maximum = current = sum(l[:digits])
    for i in range(0, len(l)-digits):
        current = current - l[i] + l[i+digits]
        if current > maximum: maximum = current
    return maximum
```

Comment: Instead of summing on every step, you could check whether the number you left is smaller or larger than the new number you got. If its larger, then you calculate the new max, otherwise you just move on

Comment: @elssar: That would discard the information *which* number I removed, making the final calculation incorrect.

Comment: I think you need to do `new = new - a[i] + a[i+50000]`, because otherwise you get a sum of numbers that are not completely consecutive.

Comment: `for i in xrange(50000, len(a)-50000):  
        if a[i]>a[i-50000]:
            #new maximum`

Comment: Your code is very nice but it isn't working. I tested with a number which largest digit sum I know, and it is mistaken.

Comment: You're right, and @ThijsvanDien figured out the problem. I renamed the variables to make more sense and corrected the logic. Sorry.

Comment: @user2204926 Well, then you didn't copy or modify it correctly for that case. The code works fine for me (output 61).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def maxSumOfNConsecutiveDigits(number,numberConsecutiveDigits):
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    consecutiveSum = sum(digits[:numberConsecutiveDigits])
    largestSum = consecutiveSum
    for i in xrange(numberConsecutiveDigits,len(digits)):
        consecutiveSum += (digits[i]- digits[i - numberConsecutiveDigits])
        largestSum = max(largestSum, consecutiveSum)
    return largestSum
print maxSumOfNConsecutiveDigits(5**150000,50000)
```

Comment: Some more descriptive variable names wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You really need to at least provide minimal comments for your code. (Even if they're just trivial cases as per the above.)