# How to solve subset sum problem with array of size sum+1

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Since the problem isn't new and there is a lot of algorithms that solve it I supposed that the question can be duplicating but I didn't find any.

There is a set of an elements. The task is to find is there a subset with the sum equal to some `s` variable.

Primitive solution is straightforward and can be solved in exponential time. DP recursive approach propose to add memoization to reduce complexity or working with a 2D array (bottom-up).

I found another one in the comment on geeksforgeeks but can't understand how it works.

```py
def is_subset_sum(a, s):
    n = len(a)
    res = [False] * (s + 1)
    res[0] = True
    for j in range(n):
        i = s
        while i >= a[j]:
            res[i] = res[i] or res[i - a[j]]
            i -= 1
    return(res[s])
```

Could someone please explain the algorithm? What an elements of the array is actually meaning? I'm trying to trace it but can't handle with it.

Comment: yes, it's not a new question and it already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600935/python-sum-of-n-consecutive-digits-of-a-large-number

Comment: @Adam4HD: That's a completely different, unrelated problem.

Comment: This algorithm is just a 2D table solution optimized to only keep a single table row at a time.

Comment: @user2357112 that's why I asked to explain the 2D approach too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting words to the code: trying each element in the list in turn, set a temporary variable, `i`, to the target sum. While `i` is not smaller than the current element, `a[j]`, the sum equal to the current value of `i` is either (1) already reachable and marked so, or (2) is reachable by adding the current element, `a[j]`, to the sum equal to subtracting the current element from the current value of `i`, which we may have already marked. We thus enumerate all the possibilities in `O(s * n)` time and `O(s)` space. (`i` might be a poor choice for that variable name since it's probably most commonly seen representing an index rather than a sum. Although, in this case, the sums we are checking are themselves also indexes.)

Comment: Sounds great, I understand how the code works. But what exactly contain the tmp array? It's look like we're tracking smthng but I can't grasp. Is this a possibility to reach that exactly sum with that exactly element of the array?

Comment: @Alex_H the only word, `tmp`, I can find on this page is in your comment. What do you mean? There is one (not temporary) Python list, called `res`, that stores boolean values,  indicating if the sum, `i`, can be reached with some subset. `i` is an integer value that ranges over the sums we are testing.

Comment: @Alex_H we are tracking the possibility of reaching `i` either without `a[j]` (if `res[i]` is already `True`) or with `a[j]` (if `res[i - a[j]]` is `True`).